# Script only working for one div out of ten

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

I have a script that makes my div fade out and fade into another div. The code works but I have 10 divs I want it to work for and right now it only works for the first div in order.

```
$('#content').click(function(e){    
$('#content').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#backside').fadeIn('slow');
});
});

$('#backside').click(function(e){    
$('#backside').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(' #content').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/981/

Comment: IDs must be unique, you may find the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) as well as classes (`id`s must be unique) to achieve the desired effect:

```
$('.content').click(function (e) {
   $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('.backside').click(function (e) {
   $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $(this).prev().fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/983/

Comment: @mylirolponi - no problem! Both `.next()` and `.prev()` get the sibling **directly** in front or behind the element so keep this in mind if you change the structure of your HTML.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have used *id* as a selector which should be unique. Try with *class* selector if  you want your expected result.

```
$('.content').click(function(e){    
$(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).next('.backside').fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

And change the markup to set these classes *(content & backside)* on their respective elements.

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: This is a perfect example of what classes should be used for. I'm not sure you would have to say `$('.content').fadeOut` you can say `$(this).fadeOut` because $(this) now has the context of the parent event handler.

Comment: @edhedges yes of-course you are write. I have made that correction as well thanks :)

Comment: Now all the divs fade out/in at the same time. I want it to be unique for everyone of them so I guess I have to add something to the script to put values for each div?